# .htaccess mod_rewrite help: If incoming URL =, then go to X

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, http

I'm looking for a little help with .htaccess

We have multiple domains assigned to our host. When one particular URL is used, we want users to be redirected to the appropriate language section of the the site. In other words:
IF HTTP_Referrer = http://www.mysitea.com, then rewrite them to http://www.mysiteb.com/fr

I'm not terribly familiar with the format or syntax for Apache .htaccess rules. Help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect using 301 in .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage.php http://www.example.com/newpage.html
Redirect 301 /oldpage2.php http://www.example.com
```

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817663/htaccess-rewrite-rule-rewriting-301-redirects)

Comment: i don't want to redirect and i want rewrite